# Get a list of PowerApps

Tags: powershell, powerapps

Add-PowerAppsAccount
I am using this script to get information in 2 columns ( AppName and DisplayName )

```
$environments = Get-PowerAppEnvironment
foreach($environ in $environments.EnvironmentName)
{
    $apps = Get-AdminPowerApp -EnvironmentName $environ    
    $apps | Select-Object AppName, DisplayName 
}
```

How could I modify this script to show a new column with an owner property ?

Thanks!

Comment: [PowerShell support for Power Apps#Display the number of apps each user owns](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/admin/powerapps-powershell#display-the-number-of-apps-each-user-owns) suggests that `Get-AdminPowerApp` outputs objects with an `Owner` column, so you'd just include that with the other two properties you're selecting.

Comment: I tried but don't know the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($environ in $environments){
 $environ.DisplayName
 $environ.EnvironmentName
}
```

This will display your App name and display name and you can easily add them to your variables

```
foreach($environ in $environments){
 $appDispalyName= $environ.DisplayName
$appName=$environ.EnvironmentName
}
```